# Angularjs on click refresh view to get latest json data

Tags: json, http, angularjs

I am using Angularjs and I need to refresh a view only not whole page. How can i do this using Angularjs.

I have used `$http` service to get a data from json file and that's why I need to update cache to get latest values from json.

```
$http.get('json/dashboard-home.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.campaigns = data; });
```

Currently if I changed any value in json file it's not reflecting on a page when I refresh page. every time I need to clear cache to view latest value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the cache of $http to prevent your behavior.

```
$http({
   // ...
   cache: false,
   // ...
});
```

Comment: I have disabled the cache, but I have a refresh button in a app to load latest values.

Comment: If you change your scopes, they are supposed to update automatically in your view. Can you post some code to check what is really going on?

Comment: Is it in your controller or a directive/factory?

Comment: Are you doing your Ajax with a timeout function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36327/discussion-between-jquery-finder-and-l105)

Comment: hi
I am not using timeout
below is code to get json
$scope.method = 'GET'; 
$scope.url = 'json/dashboard-home.json'; 

$http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: false}).success(function(data) { 
$scope.campaigns = data;

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with AngularJS i don't see Angular caching json data for me anytime. Check your cache headers in the response, maybe the underlying ajax framework is honoring it. The only thing i see angular cache is partials\template, but that is also done at templatecache level not at `$http` service level.