# Getting latest Json from Apache2 server with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, apache2, browser-cache

I have some **jsons** on my **apache2** server and I get my data in my **controllers**, usually with no problems.
Sometimes when I update a json, my App doesn't seem to get the latest data. I found out that it's caused by browser's cache and when I clean it my App sees the latest data and my works perfectly.
I found [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444223/angularjs-on-click-refresh-view-to-get-latest-json-data) but the solution does not seem to fit my situation.

myController:

```
myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope", "$http",  
                  function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('http://localhost/myjson.json').success(function(data){

          $scope.data=data;
          console.log(data);
    )}
}]);
```

In my html I usually do something like:

```
<div class="example-class">{{data.justATest}}</div>
```

I was asking myself:

- *Is there any way to fetch always the latest data?* (If yes, what's the way to do it in AngularJS?)
- *Is my problem caused by browser's cache?* (If yes, how can I solve and avoid it?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with @TechM9iac answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411060/angularjs-browser-cache-issues).

As him said: *the solution would be to add query strings representing timestamp or session id to your files.*

So I'm able to get ALWAYS the fresh jsons by adding **?r=<%= session.getId()%** in my $http.get() call, like:

```
myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope", "$http",  
                  function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('http://localhost/myjson.json
               ?r=<%= session.getId()%').success(function(data){

              $scope.data=data;
              console.log(data);
    )}
 }]);
```

So, to answer my question it was definely browser's cache fault and the way to solve it is adding query strings representing timestamp or session id to my files in order to always force the browser to get latest data.

Comment: is this syntax right? Are you missing a `>` after the last %?

Comment: It's a pretty old answer but I managed to find the source code and  `<%= session.getId()%` seems to be correct.