# AngularJS browser cache issues

Tags: angularjs, caching

Good morning, I have a web application in production environement. The users are using it every day, when I publish an update and a user comes back to the web application he views the old version of the web application. He needs to refresh the browser to load the new version. How can I solve this problem? I cannot tell hundreds of users to refresh the page every time I publish an update (3-4 times a week).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add **query strings representing timestamp or session id** to your files.

For e.g., in our spring applications, we simply use :

```
<script src="js/angular/lib/app.js?r=<%= session.getId()%>"></script>
```

You can implement the same solution in your server specific implementation too.

Comment: if i understand  i need to change the "index.html" and adding a timestamp on the querystring of the files. So that is a server side processing task right? (i also found some posts regardint appending a "version" number to the include files)

Comment: Yes exactly. For each and every resource that you load, add a querystring that is non-static [For example : session id or timestamp] after the end of the resource URL.

Comment: how can i automate this task? i have about 80 resources (javascript files and partial views)

Comment: If you're asking about Ajax Calls, you can develop a common method for making all ajax calls, and then append a query string at the end of each and every url .. And for static server resources, you don't have any AUTOMATED way to do so.

Comment: thank you i solved addint timestamp, and it is replacesd every time i publish an update to the web application

Comment: In PHP, using ``<?= md5(time()) ?>`` is better

Comment: Oh... that's so dumb... and brilliant !  I would've never thought of that.  Genius!

Comment: so when i look at my browser console, the queries for the JS files dont' actually include a session id, as the text can't be resolved to anything., and the query for the JS file isn't actually unique.

Answer (score 13):

The classic cache problem. Unless told otherwise (by the webserver) the browser is going to cache assets based on the files name. So when it sees the same script/style/image with the same name it will [304](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) and serve the cached version. There are several ways around this, you can:

Configure the webserver to tell browsers not to cache the file. This is obviously inefficient as the user will have to download the same file time and time again.

Append a query string parameter to the filename such as `my-angular-code.js?x=123`, again inefficient.

Fingerprint your assets. This is neatly explained in Rails' [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) documentation. There are several ways to achieve this, there are [grunt tasks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-asset-fingerprint) and [gulp tasks](https://github.com/vincentmac/gulp-fingerprint) also available for this. Essentially it is the process of changing the file name only when the contents changes, forcing the browser to consider it a new file.

Comment: This looks promising. Need to give this a try.

Comment: @juco why is appending query string to the filename inefficient?

Comment: @AnilVangari I'm guessing for the same reason the first option is inefficient: the browser will always send a new request for the file (if the query string is dynamic).

Comment: what about generating resource urls like '/js/{$release_id}/my-angular-code.js' where '{$release_id}' is for example an unique id of the release ?

Comment: Decent solution @Massimo - same outcome as changing the filename

Comment: I don't think the querystring is inefficient.  It is if it changes all the time, but if you do . ?version=2.5.1 and update the version when an update happens then there should be no problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using HTML5, then you can use the [Application Cache](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#appcache).  It will automatically check for updates and you can prompt the user to refresh the cache.

Here are some good tutorials on how to use it:

[A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

[Using the application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)

[Let's take this offline](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) (offline web applications)

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to understand what's happening server side right now. Understand and [configure `Cache-Control` and `Etag`](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching). While you can use query string parameters, [file fingerprinting is a better technique](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#invalidating-and-updating-cached-responses) since proxy servers will be allowed to cache the file.

The idea is that you set your documents that can change (if you have an Angular app this is most likely just your `index.html`) to `no-cache` and aggressively cache resources that that document references. When you release a new build, your resources are all renamed and when a request comes in everything works as expected.

I use [grunt-rev](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev) in my Angular app. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

The First step is get the timestamp and pass the timestamp as query Parameter in the URL for .html extensions.

While loading html content every time it will render with different routes since the timestamp is append to the URL.

EXAMPLE:

```
var date = new Date().getTime().toString();
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
}])
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/app',
    cache: false,
    templateUrl: 'views/app.html'**+'?t='+ date**
  })
.state('app.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    cache: false,
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl as showCase',
    templateUrl: 'components/dashboard/dashboard.view.html'**+'?t=' + date** ,
  })
```

Comment: on this line 
` templateUrl: 'views/app.html'**+'?t='+ date**` 
 What is the point of the wildcards?