# AngularJS: How to attach query string to the files

Tags: angularjs

I have a web application. When I publish an update and a user comes back to the web application he views the old version of the web application.

The issue is already explained in [AngularJS browser cache issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411060/angularjs-browser-cache-issues)

I found few solution for this:

1) Attach a timestamp as a query string

```
$rootScope.timestamp=new Date().getTime();
```

Ex: `<script src="js/app.js?{{timestamp}}"></script>`

But here I am not getting the timestamp value (1462333504682) instead it appends `{{timestamp}}` only.

2) Keep all resources (js, webpages )in version folder.

Whenever we do new project version we take the resource from that version only.

Ex: Suppose we have project version 1.2 then we load resources related to 1.2

```
<script src="1.2/js/app.js"></script>
```

If we do version 1.3 then

```
<script src="1.3/js/app.js"></script>
```

My question is how to append the String (timestamp or version) using angualar?

Note: With java script I can append the String

```
<script>document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/app.js?t=" + Date.now() + "'><\/script>");</script>
```

Comment: Can u please tell me which html tag have ng-app attribute. for first solution you have tried ng-app directive should be on <html> tag

Comment: I did not get you. The html tag has ng-app attribute (<html data-ng-app="myApp">)

Comment: and controller ?. scope variables are available in view of corresponding  controller

Comment: Use a build tool that supports static asset revisioning. [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/long-term-caching.html), [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev), etc

Comment: @Bharat Bhushan: Yes. I can print the value anywhere in the page. But not able to append to the script.